# Use my extra mouse buttons as a letter

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, hotkeys

How can I set my extra mouse buttons to act as a letter?

I have tried many softwares but none of them have an option to set mouse keys to alphabets.

I have Windows 10 X Mouse, Mouse Manager and many others

It is a local company mouse, it doesn't have any softwares but X Mouse can change the extra buttons to other keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> but can't change it to a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) and try the following macro which covers all the standard buttons:

```
LButton::a
RButton::b
MButton::c
XButton1::d
XButton2::e
WheelUp::f
WheelDown::g
WheelLeft::h
WheelRight::i
```

After trying this, keep only the line for the mouse button you need and modify its letter according to your needs.

If your mouse has even more additional extra buttons, you typically cannot address them directly in the AutoHotKey. But if you can (using Mouse X etc.) make them to produce for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, you can catch these keys and transform them to a letter:

```
^!F7::j
^!F8::k
```